# insufficient funds for gas * price + value ropsten

Tags: truffle, ether, ropsten

While deploying contract to ropsten tesnet (`truffle migrate --network ropsten`) I am getting an error:

```
insufficient funds for gas * price + value

  ropsten: {
      network_id: 3,
      host: "localhost",
      port:  8545,
      gas:   4698712,
      gasPrice:   65000000000,
      from: '14e6b19304fb3c98a73acea5f80d2c056ee5c09f'

    }
```

The configuration in truffle.js is given above. I have 1 test ether in my wallet account. How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

For me this error has always meant that I have not been fully synced. I have *thought* that all is fine but when I've checked my account locally I've noticed that I have no balance.

So make sure you are all synced up. Your configuration looks ok.

Comment: Yeah. eth.syncing returns  {
  currentBlock: 1820272,
  highestBlock: 3707312,
  knownStates: 3511302,
  pulledStates: 3509154,
  startingBlock: 538105
}
How much time does it take to get completely synced. ?

Comment: Depends largely on your setup. Might takes days or even a week. Or you can use a light node and get synced in a few minutes. If you have further questions about the sync process please ask a new question or check numerous other sync questions in this site

Comment: I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this error even though **there is ETH on the account** it is because your gasLimit and gas price exceeds the amount of ETH available.

For instance let's suppose that I have a gas limit of 8 000 000 (aka gas when you use [sendtransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) ) and a gasPrice of 200Gwei that means that you will need to have 8000000×200000000000 wei = 1.6 ETH available on your account. Of course that doesn't mean your transaction will use all this gas but it needs to be there as you have to send it along even if it is a simple call to a transfer fonction of an ERC20. If we go down to 3000000 gas limit we would need only 0.6 ETH

So to make it short make sure that your gas limit is set to a reasonable amount
in truffle config

```
ropsten: {
  provider: () =>
    new HDWalletProvider(
      mnemonic,
      `wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/`
    ),
  websockets: true, // (default: false)
  confirmations: 2, // (default: 0)
  network_id: 3, // ropsten's id
  networkCheckTimeout: 1000000000,
  gas: 3000000,
```

or directly in the sendTransaction

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe',
to: '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe',
value: '1000000000000000',
gas:'3000000'})
```